# jQuery - click function not running as expected

Tags: jquery

Im having a bit of trouble with a function of mine .. .it doesnt seem to be triggering and im not sure why.

I have this jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery('#refl').click(function(){
        jQuery('.sliderreflexionar').toggle('slow');
    });
</script>
```

Then the following HTML

```
<a href="" id="refl" class="button"><span>VIEW ALL</span></a>
```

Then finally this.

```
<div class="sliderreflexionar" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#" class="btn-prev">previous</a>
</div>
```

Can anyone see why this isnt functioning?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the click function in the jQuery ready event.

Try this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('#refl').click(function(){         
            jQuery('.sliderreflexionar').toggle('slow');     
              return false;
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: hahaha i knew i missed something grr - is there any way to disable the href as it keeps reloading the page aswell as toggling the display

Comment: Updated the post.. use return false; or event.stopPropagation

Answer (score 2):

You might need to wrap this in a document.ready, especially if this code is before the link in the head section for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#refl').click(function(){
            jQuery('.sliderreflexionar').toggle('slow');
        });
    });
</script>
```